# Sequence of two Future.sequence doesn't work

Tags: scala

The objective of this code is to take a sequence of futures, process them with `Future.sequence`, generate another sequence of futures and process them again with another `Future.sequence`.

The problem is that it doesn't print anything. What's wrong with this code?

```
object TestFutures extends App {

  def future (i:Int) = Future { i }
  def future2 (i:Int) = Future { i * 20 }

  val futureResult = (1 to 10).map {
     x => future(x)
   }

  var futureInts = Seq[Future[Int]]()

  Future.sequence(futureResult).map{ list => 
     list.foreach( y => futureInts = futureInts :+ future2(y))
   }

  Future.sequence(futureInts).map { list2 => 
     list2.foreach( z => println(z))
   }


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, you just have a race condition between the `Thread.sleep` and the futures finishing execution. You can wait on the futures completion with `Await.result`:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def future(i: Int) = Future.successful(i)
def future2(i: Int) = Future.successful(i * 20)

val futureResult = (1 to 10).map(x => future(x))

val firstResult =
  Future
   .sequence(futureResult)
   .flatMap(list => Future.sequence(list.map(future2))

val sequence = Await.result(firstResult, 10 seconds)

sequence.foreach(println)
```

Note you should not be synchronously blocking on futures in production code, this is merely for the demonstration that the future does do what you want it to.

Comment: why are you using flatMap?

Comment: @ps0604 Because using `sequence` (the internal one inside the flatMap) will yield a `Future[Future[Seq[Int]]` and I want to remove the extra layer.